# How to create dynamics between two tables?

Tags: javascript, html, datatables, frontend

I have a json file that uploads sales data for cities and sellers based on the current year and the year before.

I created a table where I render the total sales of each year to each salesperson, and in the last row I load the total of all salespeople added together.

I also have a table next to this where I render the total sales of each year for each city, and in the last row I carry the total of all cities together.

In the end, the total sum of all cities is the same as the total sum of all sellers, as you can see in the image below:

[image]

I need to create dynamism between these tables, that is, if I click for example on the "Charneca" vendor row, the city table will be rendered again, loading only the cities that are linked to the "Charneca" vendor, also updating the total value from the city table.

To give another example, the same should happen for the other table, if I click on the city of "Albufeira", the sellers table will be rendered again, loading only the sellers that are linked to the city of "Albufeira", also updating the value total of sellers.

For ease of viewing, I put the code in the plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/ZnCu5U9voDk2kiDWEw3e/

I really have no idea how to do this and all help is welcome.

Here is my code, thank you in advance.

```js
var url = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cffGIwIUVu?indent=2';

fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(function(data) {
    let responseData = data;

    //Reduce function to calculate the total of all sellers together
    var reduceSales = responseData.reduce(function(allSales, sales) {
      if (allSales.some(function(e) {
          return e.vendnm === sales.vendnm;
        })) {
        allSales.filter(function(e) {
          return e.vendnm === sales.vendnm
        })[0].Vendas_Ano += sales.Vendas_Ano;
        allSales.filter(function(e) {
          return e.vendnm === sales.vendnm
        })[0].Vendas_Ant += sales.Vendas_Ant
      } else {
        allSales.push({
          vendnm: sales.vendnm,
          Vendas_Ano: sales.Vendas_Ano,
          Vendas_Ant: sales.Vendas_Ant
        })
      }
      return allSales;
    }, []);

    //Reduce function to calculate the total of all cities together
    var reduceCity = responseData.reduce(function(allSales, sales) {
      if (allSales.some(function(e) {
          return e.zona === sales.zona;
        })) {
        allSales.filter(function(e) {
          return e.zona === sales.zona
        })[0].Vendas_Ano += sales.Vendas_Ano;
        allSales.filter(function(e) {
          return e.zona === sales.zona
        })[0].Vendas_Ant += sales.Vendas_Ant
      } else {
        allSales.push({
          zona: sales.zona,
          Vendas_Ano: sales.Vendas_Ano,
          Vendas_Ant: sales.Vendas_Ant
        })
      }
      return allSales;
    }, []);

    //Function to add sellers grand totals
    const mapSales = reduceSales.map(function(item) {
      var sellersSalesYear = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < reduceSales.length; i++) {
        sellersSalesYear = sellersSalesYear + reduceSales[i].Vendas_Ano;
      }

      var sellersSalesLastYear = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < reduceSales.length; i++) {
        sellersSalesLastYear = sellersSalesLastYear + reduceSales[i].Vendas_Ant;
      }

      return {
        vendnm: item.vendnm,
        Vendas_Ano: Number(Math.round(item.Vendas_Ano * 100) / 100).toLocaleString("es-ES", {
          minimumFractionDigits: 2
        }),
        Vendas_Ant: Number(Math.round(item.Vendas_Ant * 100) / 100).toLocaleString("es-ES", {
          minimumFractionDigits: 2
        }),
        Total1: Number(Math.round(sellersSalesYear * 100) / 100).toLocaleString("es-ES", {
          minimumFractionDigits: 2
        }),
        Total2: Number(Math.round(sellersSalesLastYear * 100) / 100).toLocaleString("es-ES", {
          minimumFractionDigits: 2
        }),
      }
    });

    //Function to add cities grand totals
    const mapCity = reduceCity.map(function(item) {
      var citiesSalesYear = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < reduceCity.length; i++) {
        citiesSalesYear = citiesSalesYear + reduceCity[i].Vendas_Ano;
      }

      var citiesSalesLastYear = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < reduceCity.length; i++) {
        citiesSalesLastYear = citiesSalesLastYear + reduceCity[i].Vendas_Ant;
      }

      return {
        zona: item.zona,
        Vendas_Ano: Number(Math.round(item.Vendas_Ano * 100) / 100).toLocaleString("es-ES", {
          minimumFractionDigits: 2
        }),
        Vendas_Ant: Number(Math.round(item.Vendas_Ant * 100) / 100).toLocaleString("es-ES", {
          minimumFractionDigits: 2
        }),
        Total1: Number(Math.round(citiesSalesYear * 100) / 100).toLocaleString("es-ES", {
          minimumFractionDigits: 2
        }),
        Total2: Number(Math.round(citiesSalesLastYear * 100) / 100).toLocaleString("es-ES", {
          minimumFractionDigits: 2
        }),
      }
    });

    //Function to create salesperson table in DOM
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#tableSales").append('<tfoot><th></th><th></th><th></th></tfoot>');
      $('#tableSales').DataTable({
        "data": mapSales,
        "columns": [{
            "data": "vendnm",
            title: 'Salesman'
          },
          {
            "data": "Vendas_Ano",
            title: 'Sales Year'
          },
          {
            "data": "Vendas_Ant",
            title: 'Sales Last Year'
          },
        ],
        "footerCallback": function(row, data, start, end, display) {
          var api = this.api(),
            data;

          var intVal = function(i) {
            return typeof i === 'string' ?
              i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
              typeof i === 'number' ?
              i : 0;
          };

          total = api
            .column(1)
            .data(reduceSales)
            .reduce(function(a, b) {
              return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0)

          total = api
            .column(2)
            .data(reduceSales)
            .reduce(function(a, b) {
              return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0)

          $(api.column(0).footer()).html(
            'Total'
          );

          $(api.column(1).footer()).html(
            mapSales[0].Total1 + '€'
          );

          $(api.column(2).footer()).html(
            mapSales[0].Total2 + '€'
          );
        },
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "info": false,
      });
    });

    //Function to create cities table in DOM
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#tableCities").append('<tfoot><th></th><th></th><th></th></tfoot>');
      $('#tableCities').DataTable({
        "data": mapCity,
        "columns": [{
            "data": "zona",
            title: 'City'
          },
          {
            "data": "Vendas_Ano",
            title: 'Sales Year'
          },
          {
            "data": "Vendas_Ant",
            title: 'Sales Last Year'
          },
        ],
        "footerCallback": function(row, data, start, end, display) {
          var api = this.api(),
            data;

          var intVal = function(i) {
            return typeof i === 'string' ?
              i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
              typeof i === 'number' ?
              i : 0;
          };

          total = api
            .column(1)
            .data(reduceCity)
            .reduce(function(a, b) {
              return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0)

          total = api
            .column(2)
            .data(reduceCity)
            .reduce(function(a, b) {
              return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0)

          $(api.column(0).footer()).html(
            'Total'
          );

          $(api.column(1).footer()).html(
            mapCity[0].Total1 + '€'
          );

          $(api.column(2).footer()).html(
            mapCity[0].Total2 + '€'
          );
        },
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bFilter": false,
        "info": false,
      });
    });

  });
```

```html
<head>

  <style>
    body {
      font-size: 14px !important;
    }
    
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid #cccccc;
      padding: 8px;
    }
    
    th {
      font-weight: bold;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #dddddd;
    }
    
    tr:hover {
      background-color: black !important;
      color: white;
    }
  </style>


  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div style="margin: 50px;" class="row justify-content-md-center">
      <div class="col-6">
        <h3>Sales</h3>
        <table id="tableSales"></table>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <h3>Cities</h3>
        <table id="tableCities"></table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

P.S: In the future, next to these tables I will need to insert a graph, where I will load the data in the graph according to the row that was clicked.

Comment: can you please provide working example on stackblitz, when I am using this code there I am seeing some error.

Logic for your problem is on Sales table on each row add a onclick event and call a method on that event and pass name in argument, in JS filter data on basis of that name and rerender your city table.

if you can provide stackblitz or codepen link I can provide you solution.

Comment: Hello @piyushjain, I put the code in the plunker, it is here: http://embed.plnkr.co/ZnCu5U9voDk2kiDWEw3e/